# How do we programatically tell if our bash script was succesful in starting or stopping mono-service -l:${LOCK_FILE} ./${PROGRAM_NAME}.exe?

Tags: ubuntu, process, mono

I am running Ubuntu Linux 16.10 on an Ubuntu ThinkStation desktop.
I used a bash script just now to restart and stop mono-service on our second Ubuntu Linux 16.04 desktop computer in the following manner:

```
mono-service -l:${LOCK_FILE} ./${PROGRAM_NAME}.exe &
```

How do we programatically tell if our bash script was succesful in starting
or stopping mono-service -l:${LOCK_FILE} ./${PROGRAM_NAME}.exe?

```
 We know that if one runs ps aux , they can observe if the bash script was succesful in starting or stopping mono-service. But, that is
```

not an programmatic solution.

```
 Any help is greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: You can use `nc -z host port` to see if `mono-service` is listienng on a TCP port (e. g. `if nc -z host port; then echo "service running"; else echo "service not running"; fi`).

Comment: @DopeGhoti, Thank you for your nice comment. What is the reason for the discrepancy between Ubuntu Linux 16.10 System Monitor % CPU and ps pcpu, % CPU?

Comment: That's an entirely different question, but to hazard a guess, it could be that `ps` is reporting actual CPU usage at that moment, but the GUI application could be showing aggregate usage over the last _n_ seconds, or possibly rolling in CPU usage from children or `iowait` usage.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, Thank you for your hypothesis about the Ubuntu 16.10 GUI application System Monitor. For the Firefox browser app , I get 2.8% pcpu from ps -eo pid,rss,c,pcpu,cmd while for the same Firefox browser app, the GUI Application, Ubuntu System Monitor, show 0 % CPU utilization. May I ask why this difference?

Comment: @DopeGhoti, We are looking at individual process statistics rather than summary statistics for the system. Thank you.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, I realize you said earler today this was an entirely different question. I appreciate your guess. I created a new Unix Linux Stack Exchange question on this topic called , http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282874/discrepancy-between-ubuntu-16-10-system-monitor-cpu-and-ps-pcpu-cpu-utiliza. Could I ask you to take a look at it?

Comment: @DopeGhoti, What is the connection between mono-service and TCP port? Thank you.

Comment: I presumed by inference that something calling itself a service is listening for a client to connect to it; the most common means used for this is TCP/IP.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, Thanks for your great comment, May I please ask you to please look at this URL, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283039/how-do-we-do-programmatically-set-ld-library-path-for-an-c-executable , How do we programmatically set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for an C# executable? Thank you.